# Xdebug extension not loading in XAMPP on Mac - x86_64 versus arm64

Tags: macos, xampp, xdebug, xdebug-3

I followed the instructions on xdebug.org to install Xdebug on my M2 Mac.
For compiling the extension I installed PHP on my machine, so I installed the latest 8.2.

I also installed Xdebug with pecl with `-arm64` (for my M2 as told by file `which php`) and and it loads when I try `php -v`. But on XAMPP I seem to have another PHP installation, which is 8.1, as it says in the `phpinfo()` on localhost.

The extension I created (obviously using the system 8.2 for compilation) with the 8.1 localhost-phpinfo on xdebug.org/wizard is in place.
When I check `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`, it shows the reason why the extension is not loaded:

> Failed loading /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/xdebug.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/xdebug.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

There it says need "x86_64" although my mac is M2 and so arm64. Is it possible that I have a x86_64 PHP in XAMPP and arm64 php in my system PHP?
How can I get a suitable xdebug-3.2.2.tgz? Or should I reinstall XAMPP with hopefully a arm64 PHP 8.2?

I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that I have a x86_64 php in xampp and arm64 php in my system php?

Yes, that is very likely. From what I understand, XAMPP is still `x86_64` and native PHP is `arm64`.

> How can I get a suitable xdebug-3.2.2.tgz?

The source code is suitable for both. The binary that is created from the source code needs to be of either variant.

> Or should I reinstall xampp with hopefully a arm64 php 8.2?

That should do the trick. Or even using their new 8.1.17 release. Their website says that "It supports intel (x64) or Apple M1 (arm64) CPUs". I can't verify that, as I don't have macOS.

Alternatively, you can use:

- `arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install -f xdebug` to create an intel/x64 `xdebug.so` and copy that to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/xdebug.so`  for your XAMPP install
- reinstall Xdebug for your native PHP with `arch -arm64 sudo pecl install -f xdebug`. The latter overwrites the one that is created first. The `-f` flag is needed for PECL to allow that.

Comment: Thank you for your support!
I tried the first alternative with arch -x86_64 ... and got a different error on php -v:

Comment: ... "symbol not found in flat namespace '_zend_get_parameters_array_ex'"

Then I installed the latest XAMPP and went through the process of creating the extension again and got the (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64') error again.

So, unfortunately, I am still lost and need further help. Thank you :)

Comment: ... and after having installed the latest XAMPP and then using the "arch -x86_64 ... " it finally worked. Hurray and thanks again :)